# How to return difference of 1st and last item in array using merge sort?

Tags: arrays, sorting, mergesort

I wrote a method that sorts a list from smallest to greatest using merge sort.  In this case, instead of returning a list, I want this merge sort method to return the numerical difference between the first item in the list and the last.  My code so far is below.

```
public static int mergeSort(int[] nums)  {
     if(nums.length > 1)    {
        int elementsInA1 = nums.length/2;
        int elementsInA2 = nums.length - elementsInA1;
        int arr1[] = new int[elementsInA1];
        int arr2[] = new int[elementsInA2];

        for(int i = 0; i < elementsInA1; i++)
            arr1[i] = nums[i];

        for(int i = elementsInA1; i < elementsInA1 + elementsInA2; i++)
            arr2[i - elementsInA1] = nums[i];

        arr1 = mergeSort(arr1);
        arr2 = mergeSort(arr2);

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while(arr1.length != j && arr2.length != k) {
            if(arr1[j] <= arr2[k]) {
                nums[i] = arr1[j];
                i++;
                j++;
            } else {
                nums[i] = arr2[k];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }

        while(arr1.length != j) {
            nums[i] = arr1[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        while(arr2.length != k) {
            nums[i] = arr2[k];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    int max = nums[nums.length - 1];
    int min = nums[0];

    int maxDifference = max - min;
    return maxDifference; 
 }
```

This code however does not work, because in the commands below, you cannot convert an int[] to an int.

`arr1 = mergeSort(arr1);`

`arr2 = mergeSort(arr2);`

My question is, is there a way to modify this method so that it uses merge sort to sort the elements and then returns the difference between the first and the last item in the array, without having to write another method?  Or am I dreaming?

Comment: Is this C#? You can use out parameters to return data...

Comment: It is actually Java.

Comment: Then you can use aome reference type as a parameter so you can change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got it--you just didn't know it.

Change `arr1 = mergeSort(arr1);` to `mergeSort(arr1);`.
Change `arr2 = mergeSort(arr1);` to `mergeSort(arr2);`.

The arrays are [were already being] modified "in place".

Below is your code with the changes and some annotations [please excuse the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
// mergeSort -- do merge sort
public static int
mergeSort(int[] nums)
{
    if (nums.length > 1) {
        int elementsInA1 = nums.length/2;
        int elementsInA2 = nums.length - elementsInA1;
        int arr1[] = new int[elementsInA1];
        int arr2[] = new int[elementsInA2];

        for (int i = 0; i < elementsInA1; i++)
            arr1[i] = nums[i];

        for (int i = elementsInA1; i < elementsInA1 + elementsInA2; i++)
            arr2[i - elementsInA1] = nums[i];

        // NOTE: these calls will modify arr1 and arr2 respectively
        mergeSort(arr1);
        mergeSort(arr2);

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        // NOTE: this is modifying the caller's nums array
        while (arr1.length != j && arr2.length != k) {
            if (arr1[j] <= arr2[k]) {
                nums[i] = arr1[j];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else {
                nums[i] = arr2[k];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }

        while (arr1.length != j) {
            nums[i] = arr1[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        while (arr2.length != k) {
            nums[i] = arr2[k];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    int max = nums[nums.length - 1];
    int min = nums[0];
    int maxDifference = max - min;

    return maxDifference;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This totally answers it!

Comment: @OmarN You're welcome!  I have a small confession to make.  Although I've written mergesort routines before [in other langs], and have studied the rudiments of Java [and read copious example programs], I had never actually written a program in it.  I was aware of the "array call by reference" issue, but I wasn't sure.  So, I created a class that wrapped your routine and some test generation functions to prove it would work before posting my answer.  Hence, my first Java program ...